# how to get the errors in management studio on a script with cursor inserting lots of data?

Tags: sql-server, debugging, sql-server-2008

I wrote a script in management studio that uses nested cursors and it inserts data in different tables.

Since many insert statemnets are executed there are many messages like

```
231 line(s) affected
```

the problem is that it seems there is a limit for these messages. So after a while they are not displayed anymore.

So if the error happens in the first "cursor loops" I see the error message, but if it happens near the end the error is not displayed, I just see a generic "Query completed with errors".

In my particular case I simply started inserted from the end (so the error came at first and I found the problem.

But how to do better?

Ideally I would like to have an option to log in the messages, just the errors, not the

```
231 line(s) affected
```

kind of messages.

Which technique do you suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `SET NOCOUNT ON` at the top to suppress these messages?

Note: this doesn't affect @@ROWCOUNT if you use it